# How can we define a non-simple graph using set theory?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm currently writing some literature about data structures and in writing I came to a gap in my knowledge. I covered how a graph can be formally defined as a set of vertices and edges, where the edge set is a collection of ordered pairs of vertices.

In moving to discuss simple vs non simple graphs, I realised that if there is more than one edge that connects two vertices, following the basic rules of a set, we can not represent this graph without employing a multiset or something like that.

My question is how can a non-simple graph be constructed from set theory? As I'm writing this my mind wanders to some kind of index set, that could count the number of instance of connections between two vertices, although maybe theres a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: A directed graph consists of two sets $V$ and $E$ together with two functions $head, tail : E \to V$. A graph is simple if the function $e \mapsto (head(e), tail(e)) : E \to V^2$  is injective and for all $e$, $head(e) \neq tail(e)$.

Comment: Defining an edge as a pair of vertices also means you can't represent directed graphs. I think you're going to have stick with multisets or some other more complicated structure

Comment: barrycarter, I would say that you can have a directed graph by defining an edge as an ordered pair of vertices eg (A,B), since that is a different object to (B,A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a matter of definition, ordinarily you'd just replace "set of edges" with "multiset of edges".

Another redefinition of the edge set is as the set $$\big\{\{\{u,v\},k_{u,v}\}:u,v \in V(G)\big\}$$ where $k_{u,v}$ is the number of edges between $u$ and $v$.  Or if we can use ordered sets $$\big\{(u,v,k_{u,v}):u,v \in V(G)\big\}$$ where $k_{u,v}$ is the number of edges from $u$ to $v$.

There's probably many more ways of doing this, and which one you should choose depends on the application.